# extract column range from formula in excel using macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

```
Sub AddNameNewSheet1()
    Dim wsToCopy As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim Newname As String
    Newname = InputBox("Number for new worksheet?")
    Set wsToCopy = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    If Newname <> "" Then
        wsNew.Name = Newname
    End If
    wsToCopy.Cells.Copy wsNew.Cells
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim bIsNumeric As Boolean
    Dim testFormula As String
    bIsNumeric = False

    For Each cell In wsNew.Range("A1:M40")
        If cell.HasFormula() = True Then
           If bIsNumeric Then
                If testFormula = CStr(cell.Formula) Then
                    cell.Value = "<"
                Else
                    testFormula = cell.Formula
                    cell.Value = "F"
                End If
           Else
             testFormula = cell.Formula
             cell.Value = "F"
           End If
           bIsNumeric = True

        ElseIf IsNumeric(cell) = True Then
           bIsNumeric = False
           If Len(cell) > 0 Then
               cell.Value = "N"
           End If

        Else
           bIsNumeric = False
           cell.Value = "L"

        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

I want to extract column and row that applied in formula. For example,
if formula is **=SUM(A10:F10)** then I want both A10 and F10 then I remove that is there any way to find out that.

My actual purpose is finding formula without column and row value.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get A10 and F10 from the formula, you can use this, passing your range to `strRange`:

```
Sub Extract_Ranges_From_Formula()

Dim strRange As String
Dim rCell As Range
Dim cellValue As String
Dim openingParen As Integer
Dim closingParen As Integer
Dim colonParam As Integer
Dim FirstValue As String
Dim SecondValue As String


strRange = "C2:C3"

For Each rCell In Range(strRange)

    cellValue = rCell.Formula

    openingParen = InStr(cellValue, "(")
    colonParam = InStr(cellValue, ":")
    closingParen = InStr(cellValue, ")")


    FirstValue = Mid(cellValue, openingParen + 1, colonParam - openingParen - 1)
    SecondValue = Mid(cellValue, colonParam + 1, closingParen - colonParam - 1)

    Debug.Print FirstValue
    Debug.Print SecondValue

Next rCell

End Sub
```

It does a `Debug.Print` of the two returned values.

Comment: But there is not a fix pattern of formula i want any number of range from any kind of formula.

Comment: You will need to iterate through the `rCell.Formula` string and pull out all of the ranges. You haven't provided any indication of what formulas you're searching. If you're looking for formulas **without** ranges, then you can do that too, using the same idea.

Comment: Thanks buddy i think that's the only way to find out that but is there any thing to remove ranges . and one more thing the formula is not static its can be anything. if you have any idea to remove range than please suggest me. i want only formula without range